# Firebase Database - Share Data When UID Unknown?

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, data-structures, firebase-authentication

*In Firebase Database*; If `user_a` has data they can access and they want to share this data with `user_b`, what is the best practice and database structure for securely sharing this data between specific users?

**Important**: `user_a` doesn't have any information about `user_b` account, e.g. `uid`.

---

**Detailed Example**:

**1)** `user_a` has a list of clientele.

```
"users": {
    "user_a": {
        "clients": [
            "clientUid",
            "clientUid2"
        ]
    }
},
"clients": {
    "clientUid": {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe"
    },
    "clientUid2": {
        "firstName": "Joe",
        "lastName": "Bloggs"
    }
}
```

**2)** `user_b` signs up. `user_a` now wants to share `user_b` data in `clients` with the `user_b` account that signed up.

Put another way: `user_a` has a list of clients, one of them creates an account and needs to link to the information `user_a` has already entered for them.

---

An important element here is that there is no list of users or accounts that a 'friend request' can be made from for more data. I have experimented with creating a short unique id a user can enter when they sign up to access their data, but am unsure if this is a good way forward and have encountered issues.

This is different to previously asked 'shared data' questions as it focuses on, how is the link between the two users made? Not just the before and after.

Answer (score 5):

I know if two ways:

- Either the users must both know a certain value, known as a shared secret.
- Or you allow the users to search for each other.

## Shared secret

A shared secret can be easily modeled in the database as a location that you can read once you know it. Your short unique id is an example of such a shared secret, where `user_a` "determines" the secret, and then sends it to `user_b` out of band.

A simple flow:

1. `user_a` clicks a <kbd>Get secret</kbd> button in the app
2. The app determines a secret code, e.g. `correct-horse-battery-staple` and:

   2a. Writes the secret code to the database in a non-queryable-but-readable location, together with the actual information to share, in your case the UID of `user_a`.

   2b. Shows the secret code to `user_a`.
3. `user_a` copies the code and sends it to `user_b` via some other communication mechanism, e.g. text, email, chat.
4. `user_b` clicks <kbd>Enter secret</kbd> button in the app, and pastes the secret.
5. The app reads the location, and is able to read the UID of `user_a`.

The data structure for this could be something like:

```
"secrets": {
  "correct-horse-battery-staple": "uidOfUserA"
}
```

Which you secure with these rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "secrets": {
      "$secret": {
        ".read": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So the above rules don't allow anyone to read `/secrets`, hence they can't get a list of all secrets. But once they *know* a secret, they can look up the associated data under it.

## Allowing search

The alternative is to have a list of users in your database, and allow `user_b` to search on some property that they know from `user_a`. A common property might be their email address, or their display name, which you could store in the database like:

```
users: {
  "uidOfUserA": {
    email: "userA@domain.com",
    displayName: "user A"
  },
  "uidOfUserB": {
    email: "userB@anotherdomain.com",
    displayName: "user B"
  }
}
```

To allow users to search each other is a bit more involved, as in: it will require server-side code. The reason for this is that being able to search over a dataset  requires that you can read that dataset. And in Firebase, if you can read a dataset, you can get all data under it. In other words, to allow search a user you need to be able to read all of `/users` and allowing this would disclose too much information.

So to implement a search securely, you'll need to have rules like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In words: anyone can read the profile for a user for whom they know the UID, but each individual user can only modify their own profile.

With this, you can implement a Cloud Function that then takes the email or display name as input, and searches across all `/users`. Since Cloud Functions access the database with administrative privileges, they are not restricted by the above security rules.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt and detailed answer Frank. I need to think about how the 'secret' solution could apply to my database and might come back for some clarification on that. I've not used it, but am I right in thinking Firebase Dynamic Links might be an applicable use here?

Comment: For what would you use Dynamic Links?

Comment: I could be completely mistaken, but would it be a valid use them as a means to, for example, have a link in an email that's goes to `user_b` upon clicking takes them into the app and display the 'secret' data. Could a dynamic link carry the secret code? (Realise we are reaching into an entirely new topic here, stop me anytime.)

Comment: That would indeed work. It's step 3 in my recipe above: dynamic links would be the out of band communication mechanism in this case.

Comment: When creating a secret code, how can I ensure that it will not be a duplicate? Would Firebase Cloud Functions be suitable to generate and send back a custom uid? As a standard uid from say `.push` isn't user friendly for manual entry (when other automated methods aren't available).

Comment: That can be done from the client or from Cloud Functions equally. Generate a code, write it using a transaction. Be sure to reject unwanted writes in security rules.