# Can we limit access to a path in Firebase based on a secret code?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I’ve been thinking if this is possible with Firebase
Suppose I Request Firebase Realtime Database

```
https://<database name>.firebaseio.com/Bucket&Code:<alphanumeric code>
```

So whenever I want to Access Firebase it should Only give access to read & Write if the code is there
Please Note this is different from Aunthicated Firebase RT Database

If it is possible then How to make it?
Thanks in Advance

I Tried using conditions but it was always giving an error on the variables

Comment: you can create a firebase function and check the presence of the code in there, or use request headers. In Firestore you can access request headers but i do not have much knowledge on realtime database.

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this, I recommend just treating the code as part of the path. So the path then becomes:

```
https://<database name>.firebaseio.com/Bucket_Code/<alphanumeric code>
```

And in your rules you ensure that you can only access the path if you know it, so that you can't read the path above it:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    "Bucket_Code": {
      "<alphanumeric code>": {
        ".read": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now in order to be able to access the data, you need to know the entire path - including the code. And once you know the path (including the code), you have access to the data.

This topic has been covered a few times over the years, so I recommend also checking out:

- [Firebase Database - Share Data When UID Unknown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53784606/firebase-database-share-data-when-uid-unknown/53784982#53784982)
- [Firebase RealTime Database Security Rules for personal app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75434711/firebase-realtime-database-security-rules-for-personal-app/75437785#75437785)
- [How do I authenticate my firebase with just a string key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50083815/how-do-i-authenticate-my-firebase-with-just-a-string-key/50087317#50087317)
- [Firebase Database - Sending payload with REST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65993204/firebase-database-sending-payload-with-rest-request/65995490#65995490)
- [Firebase Realtime Database rules for "secret" url sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61984824/firebase-realtime-database-rules-for-secret-url-sharing)

Comment: Doesn't it still make my data vulnerable to hackers

Comment: Thanks for the response. My actual objective is to keep the firebase safe from hackers or someone with the link. I want my Web App to Request/write data with a URL only and only through the app and only using URL

Comment: If you want only you own application code to write to Firebase, have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check